# Excel Bulk Editing Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have several conditional formatting formulas set in a workbook that needs to be updated every year. There's probably close to 200-300 separate rules, but all of them consist of some variation either =>DATE(2024,3,31) or =<DATE(2024,1,1)

[image: My conditional formatting]

Each one references a different month and day of the year, in order to hide unnecessary dates within each sheet. I update the spreadsheet for the new year in a few weeks beforehand, so I would want it to update from the current year to the coming year. The goal is to be able to change the year within those formulas, while keeping the month and day. It won't always be me updating it, and updating each entry individually would be a nightmare for them. For archiving purposes, I can't just set the formula to reference the current year, otherwise I would just do that.

I found a previous example of something similar to this issue on another forum, but it doesn't seem to want to work for me.

```vb
Sub ChangeYearTo2023()
    Dim cf As FormatCondition
    For Each cf In ActiveSheet.Cells.FormatConditions
        cf.Formula1 = Replace(cf.Formula1, "2022", "2023")
    Next
End Sub
```

When I changed it to reflect my needs, I got the error message "Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Comment: Consider putting the year in a cell, and refer to that cell in the cf formulas.   Then it's just update one cell, job done.

Comment: Also, afaik, the `cf.Formula1` is *"Read-only String"*, see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatcondition.formula1). Try [.Modify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatcondition.modify) to edit the existing rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a summary of the two comments:

a) You can't write to the property `Formula1` of a FormatCondition object, it's a read only property. Instead, use the `Modify`-method:

```
Sub ChangeYearTo2023()
    Dim cf As FormatCondition
    For Each cf In ActiveSheet.Cells.FormatConditions
        Dim formula As String
        formula = cf.Formula1
        formula = Replace(formula, "2022", "2023")
        cf.Modify xlExpression, Formula1:=formula
    Next
End Sub
```

b) If I where you, I would store the date somewhere in Excel, either in a cell (could be on an hidden sheet), or as a Name:

[image]

Now you can refer in all you conditional formatting formulas only to that name (`=>SplitDate`) and you just need to change that value when the year is over.

(Note that on my system the separator is a semicolon, maybe you have to change that to commas)

Comment: Seem to be a couple of typos - should it be formula = Replace(formula, "2022", "2023") and cf.Modify... ?

Comment: @TomSharpe You're right, I was mixing my test code with the code of OP. Never a good idea to do so without final test. Corrected.

Comment: Ahhh, awesome. Thank you very much for that. Just gave it a go and it worked great.